# "OPENROWSET" function keeps Executing without any Output

Tags: sql-server, ssms, openrowset

I am trying to SELECT from an Excel file through SSMS. I am using the OPENROWSET Function to Select the Excel file into SSMS

I have already done everything I have found on Google

- Including to turn the Linked Server Flags like (Dynamic Parameters
  and Allow Inprocess to True)
- I have switched the Service Account to SQLServer Service to Local
  System Account instead of the    Administrator Account.

```
SELECT *
FROM
OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'EXCEL 12.0; 
DATABASE=C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\Power BI Projects\XXXXX\XXXX\
Input Files\Processed\Daywise Rating.xlsx;HDR=YES','SELECT * FROM [Customer$]')
```

The Excel file should be shown inside SSMS when I run the above query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm clearly not an expert in OPENROWSET but I remember having a similar issue. Can you try the same request based on a .xls file instead of a .xlsx file ?

Comment: I have tried the same. But still seem to run into the same Issue. I have changed the Version of this File to .Xls (97-2003). I am currently trying to use OPENDATASOURCE to achieve the same.